# jsonp worst case scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pulling a `jsonp` script into one of my webpages from an external site.

What's the worst that can happen on the server-side and client-side?

My worst so far:

```
server-side - nothing.
client-side - infinite-loop.
```

What are possible attacks they could use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't trust the url you are querying for jsonp, they can do **anything** they want on your page.  Its a XSS (Cross Site Scripting) worst nightmare.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I have read this but as a beginner I am unsure what this means exactly.  I mean, my user has the webpage, other than moving things around as I can with javascript, what damage can they really do?

Comment: steal cookies (your session) and if the things happening on the site are sensitive, they can steal those too...

Comment: +1, makes sense, it can send any JS. So, if I wrote the JSONP service myself, sanitized all inputs, including the callback, with great care, there is no big problem?

Comment: Good luck sanitizing it...  The point is to not expose yourself to the problem in the first place.  Sanitizing is a scary business and probably won't be done 100% right.  Just only use jsonp with trusted services (like twitter...).

Comment: You can't "sanitize" anything to protect yourself from rogue JSONP responses. It's inherently impossible.

Comment: It's mostly used for feeds, so could you sanitize it using a regex check for letters and numbers only or can something still slip through?

Comment: @Pointy, my point was that I wrote the server part (Java/Spring) and the client part (jQuery), I don't send rogue responses. I put very strict rules on the input values, and these JSONP services expose only public data.

Comment: JSONP returns javascript.  It "happens" to be a function passed a JSON structure.  If you had the chance to somehow filter only letters and numbers out, you would clobber the JSON structure.  But if you're using jQuery, you don't get that chance...

Comment: @diamotte nothing guarantees that the server will in fact send back that function call, or only that function call. It can send back any arbitrary JavaScript that it wants; it's just a `<script>` tag appended to the DOM. @stivio yes if you control the JSONP server then you're probably safe :-)

Comment: @Pointy that's why I said "happens".  There are no guarantees, it just "happens" to work that way...

Comment: Ah OK sorry for the misunderstanding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the code can do anything it wants to with your DOM, it could (for example) post as many bogus forms as it wants.  All those will make it to your server complete with all necessary security tokens, so basically it can do anything at all that the logged-in user can do.

If you don't trust a JSONP service you definitely shouldn't use it.